# Deny Authentication in Servant.Auth with RIO

Tags: authentication, haskell, servant, rio

I'm trying to combine Servant authentication (servant-auth-server package) with RIO as my handler monad to avoid the ExceptT anti-pattern. However, I can't line up the types properly for handling denied authentications.

My (simplified) API endpoint is

```hs
type UserEndpoint = "user" :> (
              Get '[JSON] User                                       
        :<|>  ReqBody '[JSON] UpdatedUser :> Put '[JSON] User        
    )
```

and the corresponding server

```hs
protectedServer
  :: HasLogFunc m
  => AuthResult AuthUserId
  -> ServerT UserEndpoint (RIO m)
protectedServer (Authenticated authUser) =
  getUser authUser :<|> updateUser authUser
-- Otherwise, we return a 401.
protectedServer _ = throwIO err401
```

A type error arises in the branch for denied authentication:

```
    Could not deduce (MonadIO ((:<|>) (RIO m User)))
      arising from a use of ‘throwIO’
    [..]
```

I don't grok this type error. To my understanding (and given the signature of `protectedServer`), the return type should be `ServerT UserEndpoint (RIO m)`, which should have an instance of `MonadIO`, so that exception handling according to the [exceptions tutorial](https://www.fpcomplete.com/haskell/tutorial/exceptions/) should use `throwIO` instead of `throwAll` from `Servant.Auth.Server`. It seems that I haven't fully understood Servant's type machinery yet, where is my mistake?

The two handler functions are defined as

```hs
updateUser :: HasLogFunc m => AuthUserId -> UpdatedUser -> RIO m User
updateUser authUser updateUser = ...

getUser :: HasLogFunc m => AuthUserId -> RIO m User
getUser authUser = ...
```

Comment: If you put a typed hole [`_`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/typed_holes.html) in the place of `throwIO err401`, what is the inferred type of the hole? Also, if you try to run [`:kind! ServerT UserEndpoint (RIO ())`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:kind) in ghci, what is the expanded type that is returned?

Comment: @danidiaz, the inferred type is `_ :: RIO m User :<|> (UpdatedUser -> RIO m User)`
  Where: ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for: `protectedServer :: forall m. HasLogFunc m => AuthResult AuthUserId -> ServerT UserEndpoint (RIO m)`. Shouldn't `:<|>` combine the handler types into the output type, which here is `ServerT UserEndpoint (RIO m)`?

Comment: A single `throwIO err401` like the one you are returning does not have type `_ :<|> _`. It seems that you have to compose the endpoint implementations with [`:<|>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.18.2/docs/Servant-API.html#t::-60--124--62-), just like you did in the authenticated branch, only this time returning 401 codes.

Comment: I don't understand why GHC infers that type in the first place, even though the function's signature says something else. Would that mean to have a separate authentication check in each handler function? That would be rather painful, verbose, and error prone.

Comment: When giving an implementation for a server, if there are multiple endpoints like in your API, you have to supply a handler function for each of the endpoints, and combine them with `:<|>`. When you write a *single* `throwIO err401`, that is *not* a combination of implementations, it's a single handler! So you need to do just like you did in the authenticated branch: provide one handler per endpoint, and combine them with (`:<|>`).

Comment: @danidiaz Thanks for the hint. I fixed the type error with the following definition for the unauthenticated case: `protectedServer _ = throwIO err401 :<|> (\_ -> throwIO err401)` It does type check, but it seems rather cumbersome, especially for more complex APIs :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that `throwIO err401` is a *single* `RIO` action. But when a servant server has more than one endpoint, each different handler must be composed with the [`:<|>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.18.2/docs/Servant-API.html#t::-60--124--62-) combinator.

If your API has has many endpoints, it will quickly become annoying to write 401-returning handlers for each and every one. Fortunately, it seems that [servant-auth-server](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-auth-server) provides a [`throwAll`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-auth-server-0.4.6.0/docs/Servant-Auth-Server.html#v:throwAll) helper function which automatically builds error-returning handlers for an entire API.

**Edit:** as Ulrich has noted, the problem with `throwAll` is that it only works with `MonadError` monads, and `RIO` is not an instance of `MonadError`. But it should be possible to modify the typeclass so that it supports `RIO`.

First, some imports and helper datatypes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances, TypeOperators, FlexibleInstances,
             TypeFamilies, DataKinds, ImportQualifiedPost
             #-}
module Main where

import RIO (RIO) -- rio
import RIO qualified
import Data.Tagged               (Tagged (..)) -- package tagged
import Servant                   ((:<|>) (..), ServerError(..))
import Network.HTTP.Types -- package http-types
import Network.Wai -- package wai
import Data.ByteString.Char8 qualified as BS
```

And this is the main `RIOThrowAll` typeclass:

```
class RIOThrowAll a where
    rioThrowAll :: ServerError -> a

-- for a composition of endpoints
instance (RIOThrowAll a, RIOThrowAll b) => RIOThrowAll (a :<|> b) where
    rioThrowAll e = rioThrowAll e :<|> rioThrowAll e

-- if we have a function, we ignore the argument and delegate on the result
instance (RIOThrowAll b) => RIOThrowAll (a -> b) where
    rioThrowAll e = \_ -> rioThrowAll e

-- if we reach a RIO action at the tip of a function
instance RIOThrowAll (RIO.RIO env x) where
    rioThrowAll e = RIO.throwIO e

-- this is only for Raw endpoints which embed a WAI app directly
instance RIOThrowAll (Tagged (RIO.RIO env x) Application) where
  rioThrowAll e = Tagged $ \_req respond ->
      respond $ responseLBS (mkStatus (errHTTPCode e) (BS.pack $ errReasonPhrase e))
                            (errHeaders e)
                            (errBody e)
```

Comment: The problem with the `throwAll` helper is that it works only in Servant's own `Handler` monad, which is an ExceptT stack. I haven't found a way to make it work with RIOs approach to throw exceptions in IO.

Comment: @UlrichSchuster Added a version of the [`ThrowAll`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-auth-server-0.4.6.0/docs/Servant-Auth-Server.html#t:ThrowAll) typeclass which should work with `RIO`.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks very much for the elaborate answer! It'll take me some time to grok it and integrate it with my project. Once I figure it out, I'll report on my success here.

Comment: I implemented the type class provided by @danidiaz above, it works like a charm. My RIO/Servant exploration is available here: https://github.com/uliSchuster/servant-auth-rio